# DD between different file system

Tags: linux, dd, cloning

I need to install a new server Linux cloned by DD. In the old server i used xt4 and in the new server i want use i.e zfs. Can use DD command from old ext4 to new zfs?
Thanks to Whom will responde.

Answer (score 2):

No - `dd` makes an exact copy of the source disk. If it was `ext4`, then the `dd`'d copy will also be `ext4`.

If I understand your question, you want to do what *may be* called **file-level cloning**. This article, [*"Clone File System Hierarchy to Another Disk With Rsync"*](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rsync-clone-file-system-hierarchy) describes a procedure for doing **file-level cloning** that should help you to at least get started.